# Configure and run Ubuntu on Virtual Box through terminal

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

So I am working with a server without a GUI and I would like to run Virtual Box on it to wrap an application I am working on.

I would like to run Ubuntu on the Virtual Box and a GUI but I cannot find any examples on how to configure and run an Ubuntu image on Virtual Box through the command line.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I believe I found an example, https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-create-and-start-virtualbox-vm-without-gui.html. Other suggestions are still appreciated though.

Comment: Depending on the server, this may not be feasible. VMs with GUIs require graphics subsystems to abstract and build upon, but Ubuntu Server does not have a graphics subsystem. More than this, many servers are not designed to have potent-enough graphics systems to support anything beyond the most basic GUIs (such as XFCE) 

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you, go for KVM virtualization, and if you still wants to go with virtual-box then you can try phpvirtualbox, it will manage virtual-box through browser, so you can manage it, from your own PC.